# Firebase Analytics custom events not showing in Events list

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

I am implementing Firebase Analytics in an Ionic 3 Application.
I want to log some custom events in certain places in the code that correspond to business-important workflows. So in those places in code I use a method that I created that calls the `cordova-plugin-firebasex`:

```
logEvent(eventName: string, eventParams?: any) {
    window['FirebasePlugin'].logEvent(eventName, eventParams);
  }
```

`eventName` is my custom event name, for example `GO_TO_SHOP_LINK_CLICKED`. When I go to the firebase console and run the Debug View, I can see the events occuring when I go through the workflows on my development device. I can also see the events logged in the Stream View (and they appear in the Events from last 30 minutes tab).
However, none of my custom events appear in the Events table in the Firebase Console, which essentially means I have no way of looking up the stats for my custom events older than 30 minutes. I am sure I am missing something and there's no way Firebase doesn't allow such a basic use case. 
Can you please advise? Thanks

Comment: Same problem here, but my events are coming from an iOS app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For newly integrated SDK, you will usually see the first analytics report within 24 hours, and about 3-4 hours delay for the succeeding data because the SDK has a data batching mechanism to save battery life and other resources. If you can see that the analytics data are being logged by your app and in DebugView, it means that your integration is correct.

If the issue persists, I suggest you reach out to Firebase support and share with them the verbose logs and screenshot of DebugView console.

Comment: Do you have link reference for this information? Thank you man

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?technology=android&platform=ios#view_events_in_the_dashboard

Comment: I was not able to verify this information immediately. Thank you